# Mule4: "Remotely Closed" error for HTTPS POST

Tags: https, mule, mule-component, mulesoft, mule4

`HTTPS POST` requests are successful in `POSTMAN` both with and without `Port 443`. But failing in MULE Application with the error `Remotely Closed`.

Also, I tried to access the host using commands `PING, TELNET and TRACENET` for the host server via `Command Prompt`. Those fail with error `Request Timed Out`.

Can you please let me know where the issue lies?

**Workaround:**

For Mule4, remove the Global Element "HTTP Request Configuration" and pass the URL directly.

I am working with SAP Revsym Rest API's and this worked for me.

Comment: Is mulesoft runtime engine on the same machine as where POSTMAN is installed ?

Comment: Yes, it is running on the same machine.

Comment: You have to share details of what the application does and the XML configurations of the HTTP request configuration and the HTTP request. Version of the connector is useful too.

Comment: @Bharti Do you have any documentation URL for Revsym Rest API?

Answer (score 0):

Plese, share config details. My guess is that config has path as well as path exist in the http request. These 2 pathes combined lead request to wrong place. That would be only possible explanation for provided information.